# Möbius transformations on $\space \overline{\mathbb R}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that a Möbius transformation $T(z)=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$ maps $\overline{\mathbb R}$ to $\overline{\mathbb R}$ if and only if it can be written with real coefficients.

If it can be written with real coefficients $a,b,c,d$, then for any $r \in \mathbb R, T(r)=\dfrac{ar+b}{cr+d}$, and by the closure property of $\mathbb R$ under addition and multiplication, we have $T(r) \in \mathbb R \cup \{\infty\}=\overline{\mathbb R}$

I don't know what to do to prove the other implication. I've tried to show it by the absurd:
suppose $T$ maps $\overline{\mathbb R}$ to $\overline{\mathbb R}$ but $T$ can't be expressed with real coefficients, how could I arrive to an absurd? I would have to find $r \in \mathbb R$ such that $T(r) \in \mathbb C$. Maybe there is a straight forward way to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: $T(0)$, $T(1)$, $T(-1)$ and $T(\infty)$ are all real.

Comment: Let me see: by my hypothesis, $T(0)=\dfrac{c}{d},T(\infty)=\dfrac{a}{b},T(1)=\dfrac{a+b}{c+d}, T(-1)=\dfrac{-a+b}{-c+d} \in \mathbb R$. I suppose I must somehow deduce from here that $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb R$, now I don't see this has to be the case necessarily, for example $\dfrac{2}{3} \in \mathbb R$, but $2i,3i \in \mathbb C$.

Comment: Note that your question didn't say $T$ **is** written with real coefficients, it said it **can be** written with real coefficients.  And for example $T(z)=(iz+2i)/(3iz+4i)$ can be written with real coefficients by cancelling the $i$s.

Comment: BTW I think you have the coefficients mixed up a bit, $T(0)$ should be $b/d$.

Comment: Sorry for that,I've mixed up coefficients. Thanks for your answer, I'll have to give it a little more thought to show from there one can reduce it to real coefficients.

Comment: and $T(\infty)=\dfrac{a}{c}$

Comment: Ok, $\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}=\dfrac{a}{c}\dfrac{z+\frac{b}{a}}{z+\frac{d}{c}}$. I know that $\dfrac{a}{c} \in \mathbb R$, it remains to be shown that $\dfrac{b}{a}, \dfrac{d}{c} \in \mathbb R$, I got stuck there but would this be the proper way to continue your hint?

Comment: Sounds good.  Try writing $T(1)=x\in\Bbb R$ and $T(-1)=y\in\Bbb R$ then eliminating $b$ from the resulting equations.

Comment: So $\dfrac{a+b}{c+d}=r_1 \in \mathbb R$ and $\dfrac{-a+b}{-c+d}=r_2 \in \mathbb R$. From the two equations I put $b$ in terms of the other members, then I divided by $a$ and finally got $r_1(\dfrac{c}{a}+\dfrac{d}{a})-1=\dfrac{b}{a}=r_2(\dfrac{-c}{a}+\dfrac{d}{a})+1$. I could prove that $\dfrac{d}{a} \in \mathbb R$ using the equations above and using closure under multiplication and addition, so I concluded $\dfrac{b}{a} \in \mathbb R$ too. I suppose the case $\dfrac{d}{c}$ is analogous to this one. Is this correct?

Comment: I must also separate the cases $a=0$ or $c=0$ but I think I can prove the result using the same method I've applied here using your hint

Comment: I agree that you need to look carefully at $a=0$ or $c=0$.  You could do $d/c$ as above, or for a short cut consider $d/c=(d/a)(a/c)$.